# matlab --error: index must be a positive integer or logical -- how to make movie

Tags: matlab, movie

i have this matlab code and it gives me the error i have in title.

```
% solution of the scalar wave 1d equation
time=1000;
steps=1000;

a=input('Please enter the value of the ratio cdt/dx :');

%preallocate matrix u
u=zeros(steps,time);

%fill matrix u
for i=1:time-1
    for j=1:steps-1
        if (i==1)
            u(j,i)=1; EDITED-->>from u(j,i)=0 % initial condition

        else        EDIT -->> j==1 and i==1 becomes j==2,i==2
            if (j==2 && i>=2 && i<=50) % 50 is the time step for the pulse
                u(j,i)=50;

            else
                %solution of wave equation
    u(j,i+1)=a*a*(u(j+1,i)-2*u(j,i)+u(j-1,i))+2*u(j,i)-u(j,i-1);-->here is the error
            end
        end
    end
end


for k=1:steps    EDIT--> if mod(i,100)==0

                        figure(i/100)
                        plot(u(:,i+1))
plot(u(k,1:100))
plot(u(k,1:200))
plot(u(k,1:300))
plot(u(k,1:400))
....
end
```

Also ,how can i write more efficiently the last loop (with the plots) and how can i create a movie?
EDITED-->SOLVED

Comment: George, you don't actually have to edit your questions to indicate that they are solved. That's pretty much what the green check mark indicates when you accept an answer, which is the best way to identify the most helpful solution to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u(j,i-1) and u(j-1,i) are undefined when i and j = 1; remember, MATLAB matrix indices start from 1, not 0.